# Python 3 Debugging Symbols for Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch, python-3, debug

I am trying to track down a segfault when using Pip on my Raspberry Pi Model 3B running Raspbian Stretch.  I've configured the pi to do a core dump, and I've gotten gdb to load the core.  The backtrace needs python 3 symbols, but I can't find them.  Based on my googling, it appears I need python3-dbg, but apt can't find this package.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install python3-dbg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-dbg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-dbg' has no installation candidate
```

My question is:  how can I get the python 3 debug symbols for Raspbian Stretch?  Are [these](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/arm64/python3-dbg/download) the right ones?

p.s. for more details on the segfault, see [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=209413)

Thanks in advance